# Texturing following the displace

Tags: texturing, uv, modifiers

Suppose to have a seamless heightmap, created to be used with the displace modifier.

[image]

There is the diffuse map too, related to the heightmap.

[image]

My question is:

**Is it possible to apply the displace modifier and color the mesh using the diffuse map, without handpainting all?**

**As the displace modifier is going to deform in one click all the mesh, is it possibile to color all the mesh with the diffuse map, following the path of the heightmap that the displace has given? Is there a path viable or my speculation is totally wrong?**

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read your question correctly, you want to use the diffuse map and the displacement map and make them line up with each other, so that they are aligned.

To do this, all you have to do is use the same UV map for both images.

In short, create two image nodes, and load the diffuse into one, and the displacement into the other. Plug the diffuse into the color slot of an emission node, and plug the displacement into the height slot of a bump node.

Add a geometry node and plug one of the mapping types (UV, generated, etc.) into the vector slot of both of the image nodes (use the same mapping type for both images).

Plug the emission shader into the shader slot of the output node, and plug the bump node into the displacement slot of the output node.

For Blender Internal, the process is a little different.

You'll only need one material.

[image: Material settings]

But you'll need to add two textures to that material. One texture should be set up like you expect for a regular image texture.

The other should be set up like this. Basically, you'll have two textures, one with each image. For the diffuse image you'll check "Diffuse: Color" and for the bump map you'll check "Geometry: Normal." There may be other bump map settings below that, but this should get you close enough to see some results.

[image: normal map settings]

Keep in mind that Normal Maps are different from Bump Maps. Normal maps are usually bluish, and bump maps are always gray-scale.

There's also a displacement modifier, which you can use your grayscale image with. You'll still create a bump texture, just like normal. Then choose that texture in the box on the displacement modifier. To make it line up with the diffuse/albedo map, just change the "Texture Coordinates" from "map" to "UV."

[image: Displace Modifier]

Then you'll see a new box called "UV Map" where you can specify which UV map to use. Just choose the same UV map that you used for the diffuse map. You can give UV maps custom names, too, which might help you choose the right one. There are lots of places to specify UV maps, as long as all your images are using the same UV map, they'll line up with each other.

There's more information [here](http://thezedlab.com/quick-reference-using-normal-maps-in-bi-and-cycles/) for both Cycles and BI.

That should do what you want.

Comment: Do you think this goal could be achieve also in Blender Render, without nodes?

Comment: Of course. The idea is the same: use the same UV map for both images. Under the "influence" for each texture map just make sure to check the right boxes. Color for one, and Bump for the other (displacement works differently in BI, and it's probably not what you're looking for).

Comment: Damn the logic it's very clear but I can't realize it in BI. Could be possibile to have in few points the process with images and description? I fell like a kid but I can't reach the target

Comment: Sure thing, I'll update my answer shortly.

Comment: Ok i understand all but there isn't connetion with the displace modifier that should be the point of my problem. How can i do all this, working with that modifier? Like the displace modifier "randomly" assign the height map to my mesh (and duplicate it), there is a way to follow this heightmap with its relative diffuse(albedo) without handpaining?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought you were talking about using a normal or bump map. The displace modifier is a little different, but still doable. I'll update my answer.

Comment: Okay, there's some new information. Hopefully that will help. If that's still not what you're looking for, add some more images to your question showing screenshots of your settings and the result you're getting. That might help me understand better.